# Symbolic representation of vector function

Tags: symbolic, vector-calculus

I want to symbolically represent a function $p: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, where the eventual goal is to compute an exact partial derivative. The function in question is given by
    $$
p_i(z) = \frac{\exp(z_i)}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j)}.
$$
I tried representing the function in Mathematica as

```
p[z_] := Normalize[Map[Exp,z],Norm[#,1]&]
```

However, then I get:

```
In[3]:= p[a]

Out[3]= a/Norm[a, 1]
```

That is, symbolically, Mathematica has forgotten the `Exp`. Can I fix this?

Comment: Replace `Map[Exp, z]` with  `Exp[z]` ?

Comment: @kglr, but I don't mean $\exp(z)$; I mean the vector $(\exp(z_i))_i$. I want to treat $z$ as a vector.

Comment: Mees, `Exp` threads over lists; that is `Exp[{z1, z2, z3}]`  is `{E^z1, E^z2, E^z3}`

Comment: you can just do `p[z_List] := Exp[z]/Total[Exp[z]]`, then for example `p[z]` remains symbolic until you give it an actual vector argument.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica now has some limited support for differentiation with respect to indexed components inside of sums. It still needs a little help, but I think the following does what you want. First a definition of your $p$ function:

```
Subscript[p, i_][z_] := Exp[Subscript[z, i]]/Sum[Exp[Subscript[z, j]], {j, n}]
```

Differentiation of indexed components outside of sums doesn't work, so we need to teach this to Mathematica:

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants->{Subscript}];
Subscript /: D[Subscript[z, i_], Subscript[z, j_], NonConstants->{Subscript}] := KroneckerDelta[i,j]
```

Then, differentiate:

```
Assuming[
    (i|k) ∈ Integers && 1<=k<=n,
    Simplify @ D[Subscript[p, i][z], Subscript[z, k]]
];
% //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{e^{z_i} \left(\delta _{i,k} \sum _j^n e^{z_j}-e^{z_k}\right)}{\left(\sum _j^n
>    e^{z_j}\right){}^2}$

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[p]
p[z_] := Normalize[Exp @ z, Norm[{#}, 1] &]
```

**Examples:**

```
p[a]
```

> E^(a - Re[a])

```
Simplify[p[a], Element[a, Reals]]
```

> 1

```
p[{a, b, c}]
```

> {E^a/Max[E^Re[a], E^Re[b], E^Re[c]],
>       E^b/Max[E^Re[a], E^Re[b], E^Re[c]],
>       E^c/Max[E^Re[a], E^Re[b], E^Re[c]]}

```
Simplify[p[{a, b, c}], Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]]
```

> {E^a/Max[E^a, E^b, E^c], E^b/Max[E^a, E^b, E^c],  E^c/Max[E^a, E^b, E^c]}